# Strange errors on apache error log

Tags: apache-2.2, security

Frequently I am receiving core errors messages like this one below on my apache2 server, I really don't know why it's happenning, is this a bot, maybe? Are there an way to discover this issue?

```
[Mon Feb 15 22:06:07.217788 2021] [core:error] [pid 24032:tid 131964468254716] [client 170.62.21.191:38700] AH00135: Invalid method in request PJBo9aE9AJrgzNDCU4D1VwwQFTnwWFkyjWCASWBiFUGwIG_iOvMTerv3y39V9dIJS90dH67x-vf9QmqVOHAAh8W13PTzoqO1In6-epQjEJDC3SDxbVx7heDZS7gvGFI221aCQsWRYgi6toCfT-m6-ug-YOHlCnhSW1ViVheeHsGWFZCD03zHAF0pjnQzFXlj3rEcAEBSpEJjuQge0q_6A7qbQ9rnyBsUFIYn8ZtrjcZF0YRPecScEdPVg5o3_fmcwqoi7ZKjkUUim9WHo4EZt2VpelFSyWld5LSXfKNiBz60eeQoPONebEpVw2bTz1w198yV7mnELNCP7A4xrqNV5sq0UnxWukgCqD_ijpV01QnvV3Xo5t5Li-29cVKnTAuRqwwvPjZj6iTqEUAjRGt5YjZ0ImBXeMGDC_5_9lQHTWD8PD_7KL2_al1LN6Xi3HyO9IKqaPDRv_QTuPy50_ym79IFO8LYKwOAWYNsXA3-1C3zMLaN94zD4rVs0Yk_i0KqatFkmkwifm6r0DaD8GKS5xQXLM142Yb6vcsZ4cCUExs3Rzbh5keRzA7dFwySb2TP7jnm9QVKrZo2VzNrU-tr699gkh40pk3v6zvJqcTyoPcZbHIjxoYtVzcxmFHBr_8jVZYqVBfCaoMEpUA3fJXkPZUDpKLxnrt_9yoe7Qd_xirFJFhJ4rnXfhvRn5etaIB5W6gtctT_Dx1lj19SaquP49aa-OAxL-02cLfG6zx02NWcZbX9ECymwiH6jSa-3hX09KD3kggGvQHNu7e0PxYm_h7QIDEOcP3cuYlDs-vahTYyaaXW0VkIaaPgaaXKBNOG9GGzZSfOxjUZuWA5UsPK3eWmT3U3y2tqViMr2DjZTnQE2k6uMCGHOGkG0dpgLfTMaC9ZMQkZUS1XEIM7cJ36b6O-HQpd96WLbXgHro0bMUpf7ZtKIeUDbDbrJlPjpkG_SOYt0lfNAZOhQ9_tdc9rWjJ5-9bT3l2U5rmV60rbb1vGaI3ykoT-_L6bqGWBaodNTvd0G0vUZFHQiQ3UBrnnBhPaEUnJFtC63m-qaBLZI-oxX5UD6pujdl9UpvNE9WsTZoECxo_YOIMtPVQQqvjHNdbbAqVOVh5w6awPtujaUGfLPCcBQAaL5mMvQuyr2Yz5sB3hH4_TkYwyorrA9f7JCkDqQeNu4fM4mO09cAG6nLRq-i-krI8WWlHO_Vc2hOaA-hI_TZsNTtdfP8IKJEcrNPJ-J7e4dY1AIlngsiLsa862lg29OIMhltjYtBVVwfqLuGgubKaOwo_6SJ33at670AqTkEirsv-SMzgj7D-iCcXSV6P5YtB94TSe28USQw4GDlqMf35M8vVflqWtMe7vDklLI4WP3NNAQLPFAAK8BEFWSkDSIvVSKnHeQHqDOimuRCk9RpGOEmLtIjSQaYdS65Akyb-p5t3cmwx4AEZXifL4LeHicSkANbbv-0cG1nYCI_Wo11vsVAS8uPyFDxropjFdxsDkitL1hMUrOafVvyEp0TrxaEbIFVf-hZO6fV83UE_ndbg9RmVOwAtZi_8dK8qxZ-P4IFprQMKVb5PcLWhSyZmaS8GMFvS_tOltTtbAYSPLV8j9_JQom42WBh-4ibUCEPJ3owmQ6IN9joaFhwq3kJ-JmCdAy-1ilr3DAQdXe667iK4GhA2fI5Omgm0Iqy0UheTpUqDRO-ODejR4iD4bF2y9AJG4byzy7y7syY-Kbyjy3V83GyxEbR_AnGZk_X5yP8twvW1pdiGAglL8q76i5yxCxz_g48mjARnQ4TWMERi2p6CkOx7oZoOtZe4kc_ap095odAoopUD6Q-gSfBRqboY8LiYfrXSeu9SV09oa0mCT8zZtCKVZoXLHj9hyoQX2nSdk6HNm-ULfTL5W5vjzaxDjsad6zMXhWzgfvfgxDV-j13E5JfM6DDjR-tVIqGpqMpdFdF-sHbHCpAJxXOsBLiqHAEEx9CONQO7BlpFQUwsyie4SHbF6EKl31Y6sMdssXUSb8M4U6GmKUFe1IX0YF08X6tcModmUiZNLQiizEH_jeCkd-RzBpAR4h3l7MdLLr9N17nGRPT-tVbas5udm9YN6Ft4e3H8beFxldHhXeYsVlMM1MeGhRoczxMz3dp_5bUduxDR62UwJobK8xfcgDGI6laUGaf2ATYVz3m6ZT3znUWZ8-xNso8HGGS6VkxvKw1KSoCRsp1awqSnh79-qa9wPTnazjV7DX4R09wLPJq8YMeR-f9Ec0eUTEFVr-azzTKNnWeX76XFP898tBSEeSwgDLGd4QXjVOWXYksXof1R0DNRZEPxKaO7KADNgQKExpijkW2AGC-v6lOHUGzzjQgPI6CPk-VqmFEMm0WHzBLyb_agvjzTUKePKCwVMaA5e36ruSZQDaTJ-IQ2hCPP2vIkNQyOfVXuVxdHxMiCd28Idoc_Lqatcsfqd947ygONvg3hsR2U7XStc2Z8Z4m2QDmCuK43ahVpMVWJgkIi9VGgdECmxcjxi52TSiPdAVFwH7uAr-GiQCyDvDQ-BJE0McQn2q7mp8ecYdMfpCy5H2fMtNOqtWqKWpryCia4iltvqMhbopzNVPMySXv918JlEJJrp2O1RzVU3O2oTiILDzYG-Arz69sSBNk6w56It7vKWl9IeipBevrn42lkhKJPwHQTsebWEpr44PXpipvTuTc5VkBmIh412EnemI40Vx5YpsZ3BNQS2nkAqg10kozW6Sq1IcONwaG3fP1FsX-BG2fE6wL4jQoeI9vtjV_wOTZvjgnPBOy_uI03yYUFHT1umezuwzgF-ep0NXvICXXIi2k6VxiO509alqMaNNMpvmwKfcl9AA9R7pSkA30UFByjSz71kvhYzQ0_SFq3dOHgmGc-m_Tdq8XgXdesyUBKWqHHgyIOcEhl3tHbKbBmRz7jkynWbF8oA9BGPfOmOacrbU2556cVwFdGZ72-7N_Zk26_xKeibW6afrun3Q0yc34wQtai5u36o1Jfl6Gm_F14oeE3vXD4T9N-URq4Odxb7cRTNhNHTTF8oBNAtk57LfeRPhZy6xS4UQH5O2hAKwJKYrI0pow84SxZsMklUtdndVl7BsrCcgY3F6p1mpmUHPL3Kh4SmHIEttxGsWSYFELK_B3KmznIBY_a3ADMBF4WYTQE7S-mdaC2ZSclJvvk8xUSTRtT4CrNEb1j2fb8g8srjZWAUs3q5gFDqtK91xI5HFSTXVmwOfl0NhNfsiNI7mqLAiVduHTLShJcGFmvuAx_If2JuyV4sOJE3_vA0w2cAJvU_Wal3NQJdUgZs2ZU7_Ui6uiLGwXzlSM7u5ovOiOndxJVcNhxcgUQma82g8Uvgs0-dnmfBFfjpR1dpnVwcjLD17sxmNclA5u7NUr8YiBEd4ezD7eALuchR0h0VHU0AGSLEpOJJbNJAvvwWhjKaMBR93R9qBrt19Zefdnfn9K4hOzCUl_OXfIqKFr07UyJqGw4CDNfXEu-AtopQhmydrY8JOIvPzHu7r8GmUYnj0pH5pUkgwaVZwvotwQfzL9BtZaMD109UvtPwoZrnIsRRsZuChIdNfH0jH5vQkcisRln4wxATvExPe_ydrL7QOgaNH4lCRgMnuB5c7i7f8D9yIrX6Xh3-HNzD7Y2ehweqGeGhS9t3AcBhfBxn1tqaO1naZtQhNn81ltPFwec7yL_ES0hMvEmSzTd-LCncoiW8Gj-xVCopg4JxTpIOyoDceAAIEhrHNuY0XLHrA7WCHdp9m2BcNRgUMhpP9iuIibqb7tZOW-sQr6-r3plp_nJDFy1390qB7EHPLP2VAzBTJZbiZrkUj318tvtjhxvX7pT-ls7RTxBbI7SPUyrZ_CFbFxxhvcDyaRUmemIWyiwcNvnfnGQfp98CsqCinWK1aMC6yQP_4k0_-c70V7ARtY_1_9XZ5VM4fp_QTDiVRHP0Mbnx8Y8lf5wCL-azebbDhnooE2Q4vDryz3kqsZz2FH_XIQLhUSVdkP3-at02KRtcxSjLCnJPRO-GbHwTx33bSdDk2faHY8jWp0f-Nwm_PoA9EJ9Rnb9u-PHYE5Vy8YAapLK3e1rn4oX8CJ81IACm4GnhfNONweGLK2QVwMUk0cR0SdCFzHxyiadlOr8W1EFc-3aRbCNVUAsflX8aTD0Ut5_-eWoqW2WIVjTlL7WFziA4SA1P6QkwtvcOUsaodsB7TYpuwa3kKSt59VGHREvdRTUpKSLRdbBIHhA6SlIJOx-hdt3VdR4sJYIcQ9pPO-kqEjLDnDwqsD8i0xVdGbQ_Lzjw4UhuWmwAYZt5ywqWNkEURNR3Dacg0tNctQ4I7AG9y9HaxRSnlZxh4uOKiOcBBtL4zvLW0FoNDGQFU5xjrmM3tii_1zzRHaOf6J0A0hPhn8KbbRZ-Pr5EvvvoD06Cf7xFHr2zMHMbkjLmHLeuckhSrX7ulsrHFEveHsAu4PhYcBD5DqVZJ8RHG3MPLTBagEIKi7MvwWHxhlEtDljdA5-yz8hwGET /data/welcome.mp4 HTTP/1.1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a buffer overflow hacking attempt to me.  Similar looking encoding was mentioned here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86406/what-encoding-could-this-be-looks-similar-to-base64